# How do I remove a specific enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just enchanted a diamond sword in *Minecraft* and it gave me a sharpness of 3 and a fire aspect of 2. I don't want fire aspect, how can I remove just the fire aspect?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not without commands. Your best option is to unenchant it completely in a grindstone (Minecraft 1.14+) or by combining it with another diamond sword in the crafting table or your inventory crafting area (all versions of Minecraft). The grindstone gives you a bit of XP back and doesn't waste an additional sword.